# Link not working in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, devise

I have this link

```
<li><a href="<%= destroy_user_session_path(:method => :delete) %>"><button
class="button icon-left ion-ios7-compose">Log out</button></a></li>
```

But it is not working. How do I fix the `:method => :delete` so that it works in the link?
I am getting this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

Also, I am using devise for users.

Answer (score 2):

use the `link_to` helper (also check out your html, a button isn't usually found inside a link).

```
<li><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it like this

```
<li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :class => "button icon-left ion-ios7-compose", :method => :delete %></li>
```